# Unity objects not rotating around pivot point

Tags: unity, rotation

Suddenly, for some reason, objects in the unity editor started rotating around their center of gravity (at least that's what I think is going on) instead of their pivot point. I tried placing the object inside an empty object which would serve as the new pivot point, like usual, but this did not change anything. Is this some setting or some updated feature? How can I stop it?

Comment: This is using the Editor tools to rotate, or rotating from within a script?

Comment: This could be related to the 4.1, 4.2 and 4.3 updates when they added 2D support, objects can be defaulted to an average pivot point of itself and child objects instead of the specific pivot of the item selected. There is a setting you can change on the [toolbar](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Toolbar.html) to show you which pivot you currently have displayed. This affects what the pivot point is for all transforms within the editor.

Comment: @Blue could you make your comment into an answer so this question can be flagged as answered after David has accepted it? Thanks.

Comment: Done and done. I was just commenting while reviewing - :P Didn't occur to me to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be related to the 4.1, 4.2 and 4.3 updates when they added 2D support.

Objects can be defaulted to an average pivot point of itself and child objects instead of the specific pivot of the item selected. There is a setting you can change on the toolbar to show you which pivot you currently have displayed.

This affects what the pivot point is for all transforms within the editor:

[image: Toolbar Pivot Image]

Comment: Thank you. I spent a lot of time today in complete confusion about how this could have changed in the middle of my project.